# Finding the time between two entries from an employee

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am currently working on an excel document. A list of employees will be submitting their name at different time frames. My goal is to have it calculate the time since their last entry.

Since there is more then one employee I can't just tell it to look at the above row.

I have tried looking online but I didn't seem to find the documentation for what I needed.

What needs to happen:

1. Code or formula looks at the employee name from the last submission (J:J)
2. Code or formula finds the last occurrence of that name in the above rows.
3. Code or formula takes the time frame on that row he just found. (G:G)
4. Code or formula prints that timestamp in the last submitted row to the left. (K:K)

[image: Update Sample Picture of Excel]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: MAXIFS seems like it could be useful, but some sample data and the expected result (as well as what you have tried so far) would be helpful.

Comment: My excel is in french so you might have to translate a few things to understand but I can show you what I have so far

Comment: @Cruxer Try to post an example data (or screenshot) that would help to understand it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula XLOOKUP put this in K3 and copy down:

```
=IF(J4="",XLOOKUP(J3,$J$2:J2,$G$2:G2,"",0,-1),"")
```

[image]

---

If one does not have XLOOKUP:

```
 =IF(J4="",INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($J$2:J2)/($J$2:J2=J3),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have XLOOKUP in my excel functions most likely because I don't have the latest Excel version.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong as I am getting a formula error while using both . Would you mind explaining to me what the "AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($J$2:J2)/($J$2:J2=J3),1)" does I would like to learn how to do it in the future. Thank you :)

Comment: Aggregate is an aggregate of many functions the 14 uses Large function.  the `7` ignores errors and the `ROW($J$2:J2)/($J$2:J2=J3)` creates an array of errors and row numbers based on the `$J$2:J2=J3` being false or true respectively.  Then the `1` returns the max row number.  As to why it is not working, what version do you have? What cell did you put the formula in? and did you translate the functions correctly?  You may need to use `;` instead of `,` depending on your local settings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help now I understand a little more what I'm doing and yes I did translate it but I forgot to swap some comas for semi-colons.